# Verts/ Edges can only have one material

Tags: materials, vertices, screw-modifier

[image: Verts Colour]

An objects with multiple faces can be assigned multiple materials, but it seems that vertices and edges can only share one material? I would expect that assign would also work for non faces, but apparently that is not the case.

**Edit**: In the comments below it has been pointed out that only Faces can be rendered and have materials. In the example the red material has no face connected to it, is only an edge, and yet can rendered via the modifier which creates the faces. It appears the basic mechanism is in place to make it possible to separate the materials further in this way, but is - perhaps for lack of interest - not yet coded.

For those who ask why would you need it? In Edit mode you have have a design flexibly that is not easily recreated when tabbing in and out of Object mode.

Ter info: The setup above is with the screw modifier. [Blender 2.78]

[image]

Comment: Why would you assign a material to vertices/edges? Only faces are actually rendered anyway.

Comment: In the example image the two red ribbons are edges and yes they can be rendered. The advantage of this setup is it is non destructive and easier to interact in one setup.

Comment: They are edges indeed, but it's still the faces being rendered. But if I understand this correctly, you want to add several materials to the same face(s) made by the edges?

Comment: For example if one of the red ribbons was another color. Right now the only solution is making a face or creating a separate object. I just want to confirm that Assigning separate materials is not possible with edges and vertices.

Comment: Ah, I see. I actually haven't experimented with that, so I can't really comment on that.

Comment: All the assumptions in the questions are wrong. Faces can only have **one material at a time**, and you cannot assing materials to anything other than faces because they have no renderable geometry

Comment: Technically, you can apply several materials onto one face, although not directly. The easiest method is using masks.

Comment: @Duarte - I have updated my phrasing to 'An object with multiple faces...' As mentioned in my first comment, the red edges can be rendered i.e. via a modifier.